# Howto prevent grubpc 2.02 from displaying submenu?

Tags: grub2

In the past, we could tweak `grub-pc` so that it simply shows all OSes/options as a simple list, by slightly editing `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`. How can we do that in the 2.02~beta2-9 release supplied with Trusty Tahr 14.04?

With several kernels installed (eg generic and lowlatency) submenu is boring when I need to chose OS.

Here is my `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: I found in info grub there is an option GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y . Is it safe to use in Ubuntu Trusty?

Answer (score 1):

I found in `info grub` that there is an option to add in `/etc/default/grub`, so, in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Insert this line at the end of the file

```
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

Save, exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Please take note that this option works in grub 2.02 and later